# Removing multiple JComboBoxes from the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am struggling to create a simple action event inside a program I am working on.
The program, when i right click in it must add new JComboBoxes. And it works.
It must add the text from these JcomboBoxes inside an array list of Strings. and it works.
Now the problem. Perhaps user wants to delete one JComboBox, so it will get deleted from the JComboBox Array, then the text will be deleted from the string array and finally from the screen. It gets deleted correctly from both arrays but it only gets deleted once from the screen. Why is that? I added both the validate and repaint methods but it will only delete the last row of "visual" JComboBox and not "see" the others there. What am I doing wrong?
Inside the program there are some paint checks, just for debugging purpose, so I know everything works except removing from JPanel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestingGround
{
    Toolkit toolkit;
    JFrame frame;
    JPopupMenu menu;

    private ArrayList <JComboBox> projectLineComboBoxList;
    private String [] productLineDefinedList = {"-","A","B","C" ,"D","E","F","G", "H", "I", "J","K","L", "M"};   
    private ArrayList userOptionList;
    private JComboBox productLineBox;
    int countAddClicks;

    public TestingGround()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("Testing ground area");

        centerToScreen();

        menu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem addRow = new JMenuItem("Add ComboBox");
        JMenuItem removeRow = new JMenuItem("Remove ComboBox");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainGridPanel = new JPanel(); 

        mainGridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        mainGridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.add(mainGridPanel);

        userOptionList = new ArrayList();
        projectLineComboBoxList = new ArrayList();

        JButton button = new JButton("save state");
        productLineBox = new JComboBox(productLineDefinedList);
        countAddClicks =0;
        panel.add(button);

        // ACTION LISTENERS
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // Right click to add JComboBoxes to the screen
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Initial click is: " + countAddClicks);

                    productLineBox = new JComboBox(productLineDefinedList); // add a new JComboBox
                    projectLineComboBoxList.add(countAddClicks,productLineBox); // add this JComboBox to the JComboBox Array List

                    countAddClicks++;  
                    System.out.println("After click is: " + countAddClicks);


                    mainGridPanel.add(productLineBox);   
                    mainGridPanel.repaint();
                    mainGridPanel.revalidate();

                }
            });

            // Problem is right here!
        removeRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                    countAddClicks--;  
                    System.out.println("After removal click is: " + countAddClicks);
                    projectLineComboBoxList.remove(projectLineComboBoxList.size()-1); // delete from the Array of JComboBoxes
                    userOptionList.remove(userOptionList.size()-1);



                   mainGridPanel.remove(productLineBox); // THIS action removes only the last ComboBox from the screen, and does not "see" the other ones that I want to remove. It should remove one by one from the screen.
                   mainGridPanel.revalidate();      
                   mainGridPanel.repaint();


                }
            });

        button.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    userOptionList.clear(); 

                    for (int i=0; i<projectLineComboBoxList.size(); i++) {                            
                        JComboBox tempBoxxx = projectLineComboBoxList.get(i);
                        String tzz = tempBoxxx.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        userOptionList.add(tempBoxxx.getSelectedItem().toString()); // Add the text to the String Array List             
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("The length of the JComboBox Array is: " + projectLineComboBoxList.size() );
                    System.out.println("The content of the String array is: " + userOptionList );
                    System.out.println("The size of the String array is: " + userOptionList.size());
                    System.out.println();

                }

            });

        // Cand dau click din butonul cel mai din dreapta (3) se deschide menium popup 
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (event.getButton() == event.BUTTON3) {
                        menu.show(event.getComponent(), event.getX(),event.getY());
                    }
                } 
            }); 

        menu.add(addRow);
        menu.add(removeRow);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void centerToScreen()
    {
        frame.setSize(700,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("A Popup Menu");

        toolkit = frame.getToolkit();
        Dimension size = toolkit.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((size.width-frame.getWidth())/2, (size.height-frame.getHeight())/2);

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        new TestingGround();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code but always got Exception at the line

```
userOptionList.remove(userOptionList.size()-1);
```

because the given list is always empty. So I've removed it.

To solve your problem with the removal you simply need to save the last removed combo box in your variable `productLineBox`. So you need to replace the line

```
projectLineComboBoxList.remove(projectLineComboBoxList.size()-1); // delete from the Array of JComboBoxes
```

by the line

```
productLineBox = projectLineComboBoxList.remove(projectLineComboBoxList.size()-1); // delete from the Array of JComboBoxes
```

In this case all works fine and you can remove all the added comboboxes.

Here is complete code a little bit refactored by me

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestingGround {

    private static final String[] PRODUCT_LINE_LIST = {"-", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"};

    private final List<JComboBox<String>> projectLineComboBoxList;

    private final List<String> userOptionList;

    private int countAddClicks;

    public TestingGround() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing ground area");

        centerToScreen(frame);

        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem addRow = new JMenuItem("Add ComboBox");
        JMenuItem removeRow = new JMenuItem("Remove ComboBox");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainGridPanel = new JPanel();

        mainGridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        mainGridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        panel.add(mainGridPanel);

        userOptionList = new ArrayList<>();
        projectLineComboBoxList = new ArrayList<>();

        JButton button = new JButton("save state");
        countAddClicks = 0;
        panel.add(button);

        // ACTION LISTENERS
        addRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Right click to add JComboBoxes to the screen
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Initial click is: " + countAddClicks);

                JComboBox<String> productLineBox = new JComboBox<>(PRODUCT_LINE_LIST); // add a new JComboBox
                projectLineComboBoxList.add(countAddClicks, productLineBox); // add this JComboBox to the JComboBox Array List

                countAddClicks++;
                System.out.println("After click is: " + countAddClicks);

                mainGridPanel.add(productLineBox);
                mainGridPanel.repaint();
                mainGridPanel.revalidate();

            }
        });

        // Problem is right here!
        removeRow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                countAddClicks--;
                System.out.println("After removal click is: " + countAddClicks);
                // delete from the Array of JComboBoxes
                JComboBox<String> productLineBox = projectLineComboBoxList.remove(projectLineComboBoxList.size() - 1);
                // userOptionList.remove(userOptionList.size() - 1);

                mainGridPanel.remove(productLineBox); // THIS action removes only the last ComboBox from the screen, and does not "see" the
                                                      // other ones that I want to remove. It should remove one by one from the screen.
                mainGridPanel.revalidate();
                mainGridPanel.repaint();

            }
        });

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                userOptionList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < projectLineComboBoxList.size(); i++) {
                    JComboBox<String> tempBoxxx = projectLineComboBoxList.get(i);
                    String tzz = tempBoxxx.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    userOptionList.add(tzz); // Add the text to the String Array List
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("The length of the JComboBox Array is: " + projectLineComboBoxList.size());
                System.out.println("The content of the String array is: " + userOptionList);
                System.out.println("The size of the String array is: " + userOptionList.size());
                System.out.println();

            }

        });

        ((JComponent) frame.getContentPane()).setComponentPopupMenu(menu);

        menu.add(addRow);
        menu.add(removeRow);

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void centerToScreen(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setSize(700, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("A Popup Menu");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestingGround::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes my bad. I will implement later on a catch exception to stop from the error message. The replacing of that line worked. But i want to understand it, why. I mean I logically think that I need to remove from the JComboBox array the JcomboBox, then remove also from the String Array it's value and then remove the JComboBox from the JPanel. Why the correct line was to say: combobox = arrayOfComboBoxes.remove(fromThatArray the last one). I don't get it, combobox is not an array but just an instance of the box itself. why does it act as an array?

Comment: @zypa well, you need to remove the correct instance of JComboBox. You create many JComboBox, but always try to remove the last one. For example, when 4 JComboBox are created, without my change you always remove the fourth. With my change you remove fourth, than third, than second, and than the first.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought about it differently but it makes sense. One last question, it doesn't has to do with the above problem. Is this the corect way that I am proceeding? I mean I learn by myself Java and when I lose more than one day to a problem I ask here. I made many tutorials but doing my first project seems to bound all the tutorials in one place and it is a little difficult sometimes to find solutions.  Thanks. Is this the correct way to improve my skills?

Comment: Swing is a little bit to complicated for beginners. And it requires knowledge about Object Oriented Programming and Design Patterns (like all advanced things in Java). On your place I would take some examples and play with them (try to improve something). Don't try to do something from scratch.
Note: Swing is out of use today (some companies are still use it, but this lib is not longer improved by Oracle).

Comment: So you would recommend JavaFX as a gui?